# How to define the Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $I:=[a,b]$ and $L^2_k(X)$ be a Hilbert space over some compact space $X$.

**Q**: How to define the metric/norm of $L^2(I,L^2_k(X))$?

Answer (score 1):

$$||r|| =\sqrt{\int_a^b ||r(t)||_2^2 dt }$$